# Storing images in a directory - Spring MVC

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, web

I am a beginner using Spring MVC , i am developing a social network android application. The user should have the ability to upload posts in news feed.

The each post can have maximum one image attached , so i need to store image files on server.

I have already implemented an example of the upload process using RestTemplate :

```
FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( formHttpMessageConverter );
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());


    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(path)); /* path - is the path of the
                                                        image i want to upload */
    map.add("username","user1");

    HttpHeaders imageHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    imageHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, imageHeaders);
    restTemplate.exchange(messageURL, HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, Boolean.class);
```

And on the Spring MVC side :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPhoto/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile srcFile,
                                           @PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                                           @RequestParam("username") String username)
{
    System.out.println("Photo name = "+srcFile.getName());
    System.out.println("Photo size = "+srcFile.getSize());
    System.out.println("Photo original name = "+srcFile.getOriginalFilename());
    System.out.println("Username = "+username);


    String uploadsDir = "/uploads/";


    String realPathtoUploads =  context.getRealPath(uploadsDir);
    if(! new File(realPathtoUploads).exists())
    {
        new File(realPathtoUploads).mkdir();
    }



    String orgName = srcFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String filePath = realPathtoUploads + orgName;
    File dest = new File(filePath);
    try 
    {
        srcFile.transferTo(dest);
    } 
    catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

This code works, using it i can upload a photo from the phone storage to the server, but, the problem is that i want to get the URL for the uploaded photo, in order to save it on database and to be able to download it in the future, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a controller which based on some request parameters and a fixed url goes to the which contains the images and returns writes the particular image as an outputstream into the response object.....the parameters would be different for different images......and combination of the fixed url and request parameters will be the url you will store in your database.

Comment: Though instead of storing images in your server...it would be better to store them in a secure storage space on the cloud like amazon s3